# Checkmarx scan through CLI plugin team ID error

Tags: plugins, command-line-interface, checkmarx, secure-coding

I am running the CLI plugin to test the scanning of my project. Here's the sample command:

```
runCxConsole.cmd Scan -v -ProjectName "CxServer\Test" -CxServer https://test -cxuser uname -cxpassword pword -locationtype folder -locationpath "C:\Users\Test" -preset "Checkmarx Default"
```

When I run this command I'm getting this error:

```
[2020-07-16 16:48:32,960 INFO ] Initializing Cx client [2020.2.20.SCA]
[2020-07-16 16:48:38,108 INFO ] Checkmarx server version [9.0.0.40085]. Hotfix [3].
[2020-07-16 16:48:38,109 INFO ] Logging into the Checkmarx service.
[2020-07-16 16:48:40,906 ERROR] Could not resolve team ID from team name: /CxServer
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter value for ProjectName typically is in this format "\projectName". You can get the the project name from the [General Properties](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/937328755/Viewing+Project+Details+v8.9.0) tab

```
runCxConsole.cmd Scan -v -ProjectName "**\projectName**" -CxServer https://test -cxuser uname -cxpassword pword -locationtype folder -locationpath "C:\Users\Test" -preset "Checkmarx Default"
```